# Qt Quick - How to interact with a qml property exclusively from the c++ code

Tags: c++, properties, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

In a Qt5 project written with Visual Studio 2019, I have to communicate very closely with several qml properties, from a c++ class. More exactly I need to be able to change the x, y, width and height properties of a qml window from my c++ class, and I also need to receive a notification, and of course know the new value, when these properties changed.

By writing a part of the code on the qml side, I could find the below solution:

qml file:

```js
...
ApplicationWindow
{
    id: mainWindow
    ...
    onXChanged: {if (mfMainFormHelper) mfMainFormHelper.onFormXChanged(mainWindow.x);}
    onYChanged: {if (mfMainFormHelper) mfMainFormHelper.onFormYChanged(mainWindow.y);}
    onWidthChanged: {if (mfMainFormHelper) mfMainFormHelper.onFormWidthChanged(mainWindow.width);}
    onHeightChanged: {if (mfMainFormHelper) mfMainFormHelper.onFormHeightChanged(mainWindow.height);}

    Connections
    {
        target: mfMainFormHelper

        onDoChangeX:
        {
            mainWindow.x = value;
        }

        onDoChangeY:
        {
            mainWindow.y = value;
        }

        onDoChangeWidth:
        {
            mainWindow.width = value;
        }

        onDoChangeHeight:
        {
            mainWindow.height = value;
        }
    }
    ...
```

WQtMainFormHelper.h

```
class WQtMainFormHelper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_SIGNALS:
        void doChangeX(int value);
        void doChangeY(int value);
        void doChangeWidth(int value);
        void doChangeHeight(int value);
    ...
    public:
    ...
        virtual Q_INVOKABLE void onFormXChanged(int value);
        virtual Q_INVOKABLE void onFormYChanged(int value);
        virtual Q_INVOKABLE void onFormWidthChanged(int value);
        virtual Q_INVOKABLE void onFormHeightChanged(int value);
    ...
```

main.cpp

```cpp
...
WQtMainFormHelper mainFormHelper;
m_pQTEngine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("mfMainFormHelper", &mainFormHelper);
...
```

This solution works very well, however it was rejected by my boss, because he demands as a constraint that all this part of the code to be exclusively written on the c++ side.

So my question is: how to achieve the exact same functionalities as above, but writing all the code in my c++ class, without **ANY** line of code on the qml side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could resolve my issue on the following manner:

1. I created a class inheriting from `QObject`
2. I obtained my qml window pointer as a `QWindow` object from `QQmlApplicationEngine`, after the qml was loaded
3. I used the connect() function to connect the signals I needed, as in the following example:
   `connect(pQtWindow, &QWindow::widthChanged, this, &WQtFormHelper::onFormWidthChanged);`
4. I used the Qt proxy to read from and write to my window properties, like in the following example:
   `int value = QQmlProperty(pQtWindow, "width").read().value<int>();`

   `QQmlProperty(pQtWindow, "width").write(1000);`

   (**NOTE** `pQtWindow->setProperty("width", 1000);` also worked)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace Q_SIGNAL & Q_INVOKABLE with [Q_PROPERTIES](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) & implement all slots/signals. And in the UI use property binding in mainWindow like "x: mfMainFormHelper.x" for all 4 properties.

Don't use asignment operator, it break property binding (i.e. the notifications stop work on that property)